# How to visualize text in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, lstm, tensorboard

I'm working on imdb Large Movie review dataset in tensorflow. Is there any possibility, so that I can visualize the text in the dataset. Like word count, length of the review, mean, variance, etc. using tensorboard.?

Comment: Do you mean as discrete data?

Comment: If it is continuous then you can just construct scalar summaries. Does that not do the job?

Answer (score 1):

As of release 1.2.0 there is now a [`tf.summary.text`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/text) method.